# JqueryUI Datepicker SelectedDate after submit

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I have an inline datepicker, which populates am input textbox.

```
$("#left-calendar").datepicker({
    altField: "#left-date-text"
});
```

left-date-text is in a form, which with a submit button submits to a php script. The date works great $date=$_POST['d'];.

```
<input type="text" id="left-date-text" placeholder="Data" value='<?php echo $date; ?>' name="d" />
```

After submit, The inline selects today's date, which automatically populates #left-date-text. I want this to be the selected date ($date). I added a value of echo $date but it doesn't work. Seems like the jquery populates the textbox when it is rendered.

Comment: Do you handle the form with PHP or jQuery? If you use ajax with jQuery how should PHP now about $date when the page is rendered the first time?

Comment: try to add $(document).ready

Comment: The form is submitted in its raw form, and php obtains the values. The datepicker is inline, which it only works as a visual to input a date into #left-date-text. Typing the date will work just as well. I can echo a script tag with jquery, which can set the default date, but this is what i can't accomplish. Maybe it shouold be done different?

Comment: You can try to add `defaultDate : '$date'` to the datepicker definition, so if there's a date stored in $date, the picker will use it as default date

Comment: this is somewhat the answer. the question now is how can I edit the defaultDate, from the body, if the datepicker definition is declared in the head.

Comment: I'll post is as an answer, so you can close the question ^_^

Comment: I edited the answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to add `defaultDate : '$date'` to the datepicker definition, so if there's a date stored in $date, the picker will use it as default date.

EDIT: You can use the setter for the default date property of the datePicker, as shown in the [jQueryUI documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-defaultDate). Something like

```
`echo "<script>$('#left-calendar').
    datepicker('option', 'defaultDate', '$date');</script>"`
```

in the body.

Comment: I had to post the definition of the datepicker in the body of the document with defaultDate : '$date', after $date is retreived.